# Interface Inheritance Design Issue

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface

I have a design which is similar to this example:

```
interface IFoo<T1>
{
    IBar<T1> Bar { get; }
}

interface IFoo<T1, T2> : IFoo<T1>
{
    new IBar<T1, T2> Bar { get; }
}

class Foo<T1> : IFoo<T1>
{
    public IBar<T1> Bar { get; private set; }

    public Foo(IBar<T1> bar)
    {
        Bar = bar;
    }
}

class Foo<T1, T2> : Foo<T1>, IFoo<T1, T2>
{
    public Foo(IBar<T1, T2> bar) : base(bar) { }

    public new IBar<T1, T2> Bar { get{return base.Bar as IBar<T1, T2>;} }
}

interface IBar<T1>...

class Bar<T1> : IBar<T1>...

interface IBar<T1, T2> : IBar<T1>...

class Bar<T1, T2> : Bar<T1>, IBar<T1, T2>...
```

Which can then be used like this:

```
        var bar = new Bar<int, int>();
        var foo = new Foo<int, int>(bar);
```

or like that:

```
        var bar = new Bar<int>();
        var foo = new Foo<int>(bar);
```

or even:

```
        var bar = new Bar<int, int>();
        var foo = new Foo<int>(bar);
```

The only combination that does not work would be passing the least derived bar to the most derived foo.

```
        var bar = new Bar<int>();
        var foo = new Foo<int, int>(bar); //does not work
```

There is a cast of bar when calling the base constructor and one when accessing the property in the derived class but this is just accessing the same object through two different interfaces which it both supports.

I actually find this construct quite neat and efficient. It is also rather safe: the casts will fail if you try to mess up with the parameters.

Do you see any flaws in this design and if so how can it be improved?

Comment: Your `Foo<T1, T2>` constructor: `Foo(IBar<T1, T2> bar)` clearly only accepts `IBar<T1, T2>` instances, but `Bar<int>` is not an `IBar<T1, T2>` instance. If you want to pass an `IBar<T>` like Bar<int>, you would need to declare an constructor with a matching argument type. But be aware that this will mess with your `Bar`property hiding. Assuming you create a constructor accepting IBar<T>/Bar<int>, you will find yourself with another problem: your hiding property `Foo<T1, T2>.Bar` will return `null`, whereas the hidden property `Foo<T1>.Bar` will return the IBar<T>/Bar<int> instance.

Comment: Improvement areas: Wanting to pass an `Bar<int>` object to your `Foo<T1, T2>` object is in violation of your elaborate class design. However, the main problem with your code in the question is member hiding. Member hiding is always good for nasty surprises, so stay away from it.

Comment: @elgonzo Thanks for your comment. I mentioned having an Bar<int>/IBar<T1> as parameter only to single out that it fails which is a good thing. And you are right to point out that the new property would be null in that case. I even think it should use a hard cast instead of as so that it crashes instead of silently returning null.

Comment: Ah, okay. Then i misunderstood the part in your question about the error. My apologies. As long as you keep a keen eye and awareness on possible undesireable effects of member hiding if you are going to expand/modify your code in the future, i don't see no problem. The way as you do member hiding now is alright, as far as the code in your question is concerned. Unless i overlooked something, you seem to do member hiding in a safe way, only using it to return a Bar property value known/enforced to be of a more specialized type as a reference of that more specialized type, which is alright...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [CodeReview.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Please note, though, that using the `new` keyword is just as dangerous as explicit interface implementation and for exactly the same reason - You will (or at least, might) get a different behavior from the same instance depending purely on the type of the reference. Though admittedly you sometimes want this behavior, most of the time it's a potentially dangerous side-effect not all developers are aware of.

Comment: Hmm, i see maybe one improvement: Note that the `Foo<T1>.Bar` property has a private setter, potentially allowing `Foo<T1>.Bar` to change the value of this property either intentionally or accidentally by a programming mistake (depending on your implementation of that class, of course), possibly assigning an `IBar<T1>` instance that is not also an `IBar<T1, T2>` and thus breaking the member hiding. I would thus suggest to make the `Foo<T1>.Bar` property a get-only/readonly property to avoid this from possibly happening.

Comment: @elgonzo - you are correct about the private setter. There should be no setter in C# 6.0 or later so that only the constructor can set it. The only reason there is one there is because I typed this code in an earlier version of C# which does not support this syntax.

Comment: @Zohar Peled - In this case the new keyword allows you to return a different type with the same property which is the desired behavior. There is a risk that the content of the property would be modified in an unwanted way but then the cast would return null. Alternatively a hard cast: return (IBar<T1, T2>)base.Bar - gives the certainty that you will bet the right type or an exception.

Comment: Yes, I've used that trick myself in a few situations, but this it still something to take into consideration and be aware of.